# How to adjust row height of a material-ui table component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Table component available in material-ui in my React JS application. However, specifying height:10px in style prop does not adjust the heights of individual rows.
Please suggest how to specify or reduce the default row heights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to set the height for all `td` to auto then you will be able to change the `tr` row height

apply this using css

```
tr {
  height: 10px;
}

tr td {
   height: auto !important;
}
```

[image: Edit wwppr4306w]

Comment: Thanks Liam, this partially worked. I mean, if I specify height: 50 or plus then row height gets changed. However, specifying any value less than 50 does not make any change in screen. I indeed want to make rows a little bit leaner.

Answer (score 3):

You can try reducing the padding of the table Cells, but you have to do it for all the table Cells. This is just a work around.

this.deleteItem(index)}>{item.name}
                        Pot number
                        {this.changeRate(event,index)}} type="number" />
                        {item.rate}
                        {item.itemTotal}

Answer (score 3):

If you are using V.4, the only solution that I found working is to use prop `size="small"`.

https://v4.mui.com/api/table/

None of these solutions worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I adjust padding in TableCell till get row height I need.

```
<TableCell sx={{borderBottom: "none", paddingTop: 0.8, paddingBottom: 0}}>
content
</TableCell>
```

Answer (score -1):

just add `rowStyle: {height: 50}` to options.

```
const options: Options = {
    ...
    rowStyle: {height: 50},
    ...
}

<MaterialTable
        ...
        options={options}
        ...
/>
```

no CSS override needed.

Comment: The above solution doesn’t work.

Comment: i style all my mui tables in my project this way. thats a very clean solution

Comment: I am sorry the same ain't working with me.

Answer (score -1):

Using materialUi classes

```
const tableStyles = makeStyles({
  tableHead: {
    height: 44,
  },
})

const classes = tableStyles()

    
<TableHead>
  <TableRow className={classes.tableHead}>
    ...
  </TableRow>
</TableHead>
```