# Material-UI table Row height to fixed height even content is lengthy in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with a listing component and I'm using material UI table in ReactJS. I've a ResumeUrl field in table which spans over to 3, 4 lines but I want to keep it only on 2 lines (fixed height for whole row) and show dots for rest of content. I'm unable to change height of Row. I've tried different ways. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50030823/11045088) isn't working for me as well.

It will keep on increasing height if the content is going to be lengthy and lengthy. I want to set its fixed height, to get a nicer look and a good user experience.

[image]

```
    <TableContainer>
      <Table
        className={classes.table}
        aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
        size={dense ? 'small' : 'medium'}
        aria-label="enhanced table"
        data={applicants}
      >
        <EnhancedTableHead
          classes={classes}
          order={order}
          orderBy={orderBy}
          onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
          rowCount={rows.length}
        />
          <TableBody>
          {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
            .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
            .map((row, index) => {
              const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;
              return (
                <TableRow
                  style={{height: 10}}
                  hover
                  role="checkbox"
                  tabIndex={-1}
                  key={row._id}
                >
                  <TableCell style={{ height: 'auto !important' }} component="th" id={labelId} scope="row">{row.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ height: 'auto !important' }} align="left">{row.address}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ height: 'auto !important' }} align="left">{row.phone}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ height: 'auto !important' }} align="left" style={{width: 350}}><a href={row.resumeUrl}
                                                                  target={'_blank'}>{row.resumeUrl}</a></TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ height: 'auto !important' }} align="left">{row.email}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ height: 'auto !important' }} align="left">{row.applied_date}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}


          {emptyRows > 0 && (
            <TableRow
            style={{height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows}}
            >
            <TableCell colSpan={6}/>
            </TableRow>
            )}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
```

Comment: Please add minimal working code..

Comment: @XxSTREKxX Thanks for your concern actually I've put an answer in answers sections. I did it after playing with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much thought I was able to do that at my own. If anyone is interested he can grab it.

I declared a style variable with `ellipsisStyle` name.

```
const ellipsisStyle = {
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: '350px',
    maxWidth: '350px' }
```

you can then use this style in all `TableCell` where you want to apply style on.

```
               <TableRow> <TableCell component="th" id={labelId} scope="row">{row.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left" style={ellipsisStyle}>{row.address}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left" style={ellipsisStyle}><a href={row.resumeUrl} target={'_blank'}>{row.resumeUrl}</a></TableCell>
               </TableRow>
```